# Autoprefixer does very little in gatsby project

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, autoprefixer

I am using the Autoprefixer plugin for VSCode on a Mac and when I run the autoprefixer command on my `scss` files, the plugin ignores all my `flexbox` properties and comically only prefixes the following. Is there a reason why Autoprefixer ignores the majority of my css code?

```
-o-object-fit: cover;
       object-fit: cover;
```

[image: Img with plugin settings]

My `settings.js`

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "color-highlight.markerType": "dot-before",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "autoprefixer.formatOnSave": true,
    "autoprefixer.browsers": [ "last 4 versions", "ie >= 9", "> 5%" ]
}
```

I was suggested to add the autoprefixer.browsers line in my settings but nothing changes and the VSCode doesn't seem to recognize the command

[image: Autoprefixer settings]

Comment: You didn't provide any options to autoprefixer? Try adding `"autoprefixer.browsers": [ "last 4 versions", "ie >= 9", "> 5%" ]` to your settings

Comment: I updated my settings as you suggested, but VSCode doesn't seem to recognize the option as nothing changes. I added a picture to my original question on the current settings status.

Comment: Add the browserslist to package.json, it's not VS Code that compiles the scss, it's Gatsby? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/